# JSON Object not printing to screen

Tags: android, json

My included code is of my Asynctask of getting the JSON from URL and attempting to parse it and output the information to TextViews on the screen. I'm under the assumption that the issue lies in the onPostExecute block of actually passing the JSON info to strings and outputting it but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I had it partially working last night, but it was only printing 0's and null. I have since made some changes and here I am.

```
class GetStats extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private String api_key="d96236d2-6ee3-4cfd-afa7-f41bdbc11128";
    String region = MainActivity.region.toLowerCase();
    String name = MainActivity.name;
    String url = null;
    String encodedName = null;
    String encodedKey = null;
    String encodedRegion = null;

    // JSON Node Names
    String TAG_ID = "id";
    String TAG_NAME = "name";
    String TAG_PROFILEICONID = "profileIconId";
    String TAG_REVISIONDATE = "revisionDate";
    String TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL = "summonerLevel";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            textId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
            textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            textProfileIconId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileIconId);
            textRevisionDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.revisionDate);
            textSummonerLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summonerLevel);
            encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
            encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(api_key, "UTF-8");
            encodedRegion = URLEncoder.encode(region, "UTF-8");
            url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + encodedRegion + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + encodedName + "?api_key=" + encodedKey;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Get JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        JSONObject jb = null;

        try {
            jb = json.getJSONObject(encodedName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            // Storing JSON item to String
            String id = json.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = json.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String icon = json.getString(TAG_PROFILEICONID);
            String revDate = json.getString(TAG_REVISIONDATE);
            String sumLevel = json.getString(TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL);

            // Putting JSON data in TextViews
            textId.setText(id);
            textName.setText(name);
            textProfileIconId.setText(icon);
            textRevisionDate.setText(revDate);
            textSummonerLevel.setText(sumLevel);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Expected result example:

```
 {"nv43":{"id":23591778,"name":"NV43","profileIconId":22,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1396737099000}}
```

The error:

```
04-07 13:32:18.359  22875-22875/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.appdesign.leaguestats, PID: 22875
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.StatsActivity$GetStats.onPostExecute(StatsActivity.java:110)
            at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.StatsActivity$GetStats.onPostExecute(StatsActivity.java:53)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{ // json object node 
    "nv43": {  // jsonobject nv43
        "id": 23591778, 
        "name": "NV43",
        "profileIconId": 22,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1396737099000
    }
}
```

You missed parsing `JSONObject` nv43.

In `doInBackground`

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject jb = json.getJSONObject("nv43"); 
return jb;
```

Comment: Making that change results in a NullPointerException here:                 String id = json.getString(TAG_ID);

Comment: @Nate post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Nate your json from server can be null. Are you sure its not null

Comment: I have tested the URL that I am sending to the server and it is providing a valid JSON. I will edit the error into my main post in just a second.

Comment: @Nate your json is null. check it. The parsing code is fine. You can log the json and check it yourself

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Nate `Log.i("............",""+json);`. This is basic stuff and you should check the docs or else how will you debug your code later

Comment: I have done this and also output the url I am sending and I have a strange issue. When I put the URL into my web browser it retrieves the JSON fine, but when it comes back on my device it reads: {"status":{"status_code":401,"message":"Access denied"}}. Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: @Nate i can't talk on that. But you need to check your server side

Answer (score 0):

Change the onPostExecute() method like below

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            JSONObject result = json.getJSONObject("nv43"); // First Create an Object of "nv43"
            // Storing JSON item to String
            String id = result.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = result.getString(TAG_NAME);
            // Rest code
```

Comment: this is same as mine except you parse `JSONObject nv43.` in onPostExecute

Comment: @Raghunandan i think instead of doing it on doInBackground() better to do it on onPostExecute().

Comment: how better. in fact all parsing can be done in `doInbackground` itself

Comment: Suppose in case json string may be complex. Assume nv43 is Array type then need to change the onPostExecute() parameter i.e JSONObject to JSONArray. We can do the whole parsing in doInBackground() i agree.